# problem with echo variable in function strtotime()

Tags: php, codeigniter, echo, strtotime

why not worked echo (function strtotime) in this code?
not displaying anything.

```
$ok = '2011/07/18'; 
echo strtotime($ok);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it worked fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php


$ok = '2011/07/18';
echo strtotime($ok);


echo date("F j, Y, g:i:s a",strtotime($ok));
?>
```

Response:   1310965200July 18, 2011, 12:00:00 am

Comment: You may also try setting the default time zone before your time functions:  date_default_timezone_set('America/Halifax');

Answer (score 0):

I personally [didn't get anything unexpected](http://www.ideone.com/ClTzi). Are you aware you're going to get a number in response to [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and not a formatted date? You'd have to make a call to [`strftime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) (or similar) to format it back.